# TS2339:Property 'last_name' does not exist on type '{ submit(): Promise<void>; }'

Tags: vue.js, promise

```js
    export default{
      name:"Register",
      data(){
        return {
          first_name:'',
          last_name:'',
          email: '',
          password : '',
          password_confirm :'',
        }
      },
      methods:{
        async submit(){
          await axios.post ('addr', {
            first_name:this.first_name,
            last_name:this.last_name,
            email:this.email,
            password:this.password,
            password_confirm:this.password_confirm,
          });
          await this.$router.push('/login');
        }
      }
    }
```

[image]

i am newbi in this field and when i try that code i expect to get data such as     "first_name" from  in .vue file and post it to that url but i get error

Comment: This is IDE problem, the question doesn't make sense in general. This is Typescript error which is irrelevant if you don't use TS in your project. Use defineComponent() to aid IDE with correct types

Comment: im using Typescript in my project and i totally have problem in using "this" in my code, i solved that problem by defining interface and i think solve it from hard way.thanks anyway